# REGEXP_SUBSTR strip unwanted character (-)

Tags: sql

I have a string "John Hull -PHD". I want to select the suffix  "PHD".

Right now I use REGEXP_SUBSTR which create "-PHD" and then I use Replace to get rid of the "-"

Can you please help to change the  REGEXP_SUBSTR so I dont need to use Replace?

Thanks

HHC

````
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(upper(SET3_N),'(^|-|[ |-|,|''|\.])(PHD)($|-|[ |-|,|''|\.])',1,1,'i'),'-','') as suffix_final```
````

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you are using, but `regexp_replace()` does what you want:

```
select regexp_replace(set3_n, '.*-([^-]*)$', '\1')
```